# Curly brackets and Big O notation

Tags: brackets, mathcal

I'm having some trouble inserting a Big O notation into a right-side curly bracket consisting of two lines. I'm using mathcal for the Big O notation but once I put it in the curly bracket it doesn't seem to work. I'm inserting an image of what I want to do (made in powerpoint). Very thankful for help :)

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post a minimal code of what you have tried so far. This kind of construction is usually best achieved with the `cases` environment from the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE: your question seem a bit contradictory *I'm using mathcal for the Big O notation but once I put it in the curly bracket it doesn't seem to work*. What is, please, the example that you have made using LaTeX?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I've added some images. As you can see, the Big-O notation on the second line is just a normal O when I put it in curly brackets

Comment: Everything in the `align` environment is already in math mode and the two `$` are wrong: lose them.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: In the future, it would be better to share your code as text, inside a code block. We can’t copy and paste from a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works...and the upvoted comment go to the user @campa :-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases}
T(1)=\mathcal{O}(1) & \\
T(m)=22\ast(T/2)
\end{cases} \implies T(m)=22\ast(T/2)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I hope I managed to upvote :)